# Why does npm run eject look through all my project folders?

Tags: npm, webpack, create-react-app

I am trying to run an `npm run eject` on a new project so I can configure Webpack files, but I got this message:

```
✗ npm run eject

> location@0.1.0 eject /Users/danale/Projects/location
> react-scripts eject

NOTE: Create React App 2 supports TypeScript, Sass, CSS Modules and more without ejecting: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html

? Are you sure you want to eject? This action is permanent. Yes
This git repository has untracked files or uncommitted changes:
```

Why is it referencing all the project folders? To be clear I am running the above command inside of one project folder I just created with CRA.

I am not in the folder with all my projects, I am in the folder with one newly created project. With that said, why is npm referencing all my other projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you eject a `react` project created with `create-react-app` they give you the following cookie cutter response of:

```
NOTE: Create React App 2 supports TypeScript, Sass, CSS Modules and more without ejecting: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html

? Are you sure you want to eject? This action is permanent. Yes
This git repository has untracked files or uncommitted changes:
```

The reason for this is a lot of people want to have a *granular level of control of their `webpack.config.js` file and you've to eject to get access to this file* as it's obfuscated away within your `react-scripts` module. Now the part of the eject warning message saying:

```
NOTE: Create React App 2 supports TypeScript, Sass, CSS Modules and more without ejecting: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html
```

Is to inform you that you **don't have to eject to take advantage of preprocessors, `TypeScript`, etc....** They tell you this because `create-react-app` didn't always support the easy addition of this functionality so people would eject to be able to use preprocessors and `TypeScript`.

You're correct that in order to use `SASS` all you have to do is:

1. Install the `node-sass` module with a: `npm install node-sass`
2. Then just create your `.scss` files and import your desired `.scss` file in the component you wish to use the styling at. Alternatively, you could also just have a "main" `.scss` file whose only job is to import other `.scss` files relevant for your app. Then import this "main" `.scss` file within your `App.js` file.

Now as for this part of the eject warning message:

```
This git repository has untracked files or uncommitted changes:
```

You're probably getting this because you've set up a git repository for a parent folder where you ran the `create-react-app` CLI. Basically, in one of your parent folders where your `create-react-app` interface is located at is a `.git/config` that points upstream to one of your remote repositories.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Between what I read in the documentation suggested in the error message and from tinkering with it, all you have to do is:

`npm install node-sass`

and then you can start changing `css` files to `scss` and creating other `scss` files for your project. No `npm run eject` necessary.